# Path to secure file from build task VSTS

Tags: android, file, keystore, azure-pipelines, android-signing

How to you access a secure file on VSTS in a build task? I uploaded the secure file and am trying to point to it in an Android Signing task, but when I go to choose the file there's no way to get to the library. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an extension such as [Download Secure File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mattlabrum.build-task) that will allow you to retrieve something from secure files and put it into a location on your build/release agent.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Download Secure File" and add this task before start building your android project. Copy signing key to the Droid folder and mentioned this same path in APK signing task.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mattlabrum.build-task

Cheers! 
Manesh